# Is @GuardedBy annotation always applicable when there is synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

Is it a fair assumption to say that if a class has a synchronized block, it's always better to have @[GuardedBy](https://code.google.com/p/jsr-305/source/browse/trunk/ri/src/main/java/javax/annotation/concurrent/GuardedBy.java?r=43) annotation in that class.

More specifically, will there be a case where we have a synchronized block in a java file but we cannot use @GuardedBy annotation in that class on any field or method ?

Answer (score 0):

If `@GuardedBy` annotation reference any of the `Lock` implementations like `ReentrantLock`, `ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock`, `ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock` then it is expected to use the concerned lock for locking instead of locking with a synchronized block.